# Saving for retirement... starting at 68 years old

Tags: united-states, savings, retirement, retirement-plan

It may sound like a joke, but it is not. I imagine I am not the only one in this situation. I guess.

Here is what I have going on. I am a "one man show" self employed carpenter. It took many years to find out how much I need to make to actually save money and collect a profit. Sad but true, before that, living paycheck to paycheck. I have been able to just over the past 2 years, kinda, start saving. IRS took most of my savings the past 2 years, since I did not know how much to pay into estimated tax payments, (including many years before) it took years just to not having to finance a portion of the late taxes. There is a lot more to it than that. Bottom line, I am counting on this year everything will be paid up properly since last year I jumped a tax bracket, and that surprised me, since I thought.... "I got it this year". I did have some savings left over after that fortunately. The year before wiped it out, but both past 2 years it was paid off with out having to finance any, a MAJOR milestone for me.

Back on track, I don't think an IRA will fit what I am needing, I haven't got an emergency fund yet, about a 1/4 of the way there, but getting there slowly. Credit cards are all paid off except for about $1000 on one for health care. One auto payment $260 monthly, besides a small mortgage (27 years to go on a 30 yr) on our home that has a lot of equity (500K??). My plan, as it is now, is to contribute into a 1 year CD, as in, move the emergency fund, or my account that I am letting the profits accumulate, set that into the CD since the money market account that the emergency fund is in is only earning .3%??? and a CD will get 3.45 if I get enough into it, 2.45 if I don't or something like that, never the less 10 times more interest just by placing it in the right place.

Is this the right idea? Of course I may be doing to little too late and should just move to Mexico and live off my Social Security which I am told my wife and can live VERY well on just that.

Comment: You can get 2.4% APR in a regular liquid account (search for "High Yield Savings Account") without locking money for a year in a CD in a rising interest environment

Comment: 27 years left, or 3 years left? Nice job building up 500K equity in 3 years if it's as you phrased it :)

Comment: "self employed carpenter" - Knowing nothing about your current rates, I practically guarantee you that you can raise your rates (probably significantly) and still be able to book clients. Carpenters I know are booked months out right now and even if they doubled their rates, they'd still be able to find enough clients to fill out their schedule.

Comment: Home has special bankruptcy protection. Think carefully about how to handle that asset. Why is this brought up, at your age, and perhaps wife's age, unforeseen medical costs. Not sure if you only have basic medicare. May want to look into Medicaid Asset Protection Trust, as your wife probability of outliving you is high.

Comment: @paulj only in certain states. OJ moved to Florida because 100% of a homestead's value is protected regardless of value. That's about the only state that protects an unlimited amount.  Most states have equity caps.

Comment: @KevinArlin, 27 years left. Yes found a turn key foreclosure, that sat for 2 years 3000sq ft 3 acres, built a barn on it, upgraded the shop a bit, tore out carpet added more matching 3/4" bamboo T&G flooring sold it for 493.5K, bought for 271K. Bought our house we have now for 431K financed 270K paid down to 258K I think, with prices still high for now in this area, this house should go for at least 700K+. That may not add up top 500K, still a lot of equity. Houses are still going for more than market price in this area.

Comment: @Brave , Everybody is but me, I have not been exposed to other contractors, subs, what have you, since I have been working at this one location. I have just started doing work after I pull 8 hours at the one place and building stairs in the evening. I did take off 3 weeks to trim a house and have another to do next month, but the phone is not ringing. I need to get my website up. Been getting my name out there to interior designers, for cabinet installs. Yup doing good with my rate but that's only if I pull 40 hour weeks. If I want to take a day off here and there, I will need to get more

Comment: @littleadv You can get over 4% on a 3 month T-bill!  Which makes me wonder, aside from not being a regulated bank what stops me from taking deposits, buying T-bills, and then paying slightly less on "high interest savings accounts"?

Comment: @Andy nothing, I guess? That's how money market accounts work.

Comment: what is your estimated age 70 Social Security benefit (this information is available from the Social Security Administration)?

Comment: @jdigital it will be $3556 at 70, my wife thinks hers will be close to $3000 I would hope to trim down our spending so that would be a livable amount. Right now to pay all that needs to be paid, 10% tithe, 10% in savings, 30% in taxes, 2% for profit, and the rest spent on monthly bills, one would figure bringing in 14K a month we would be doing real good, but that just does make ends meet, working 10-11 hrs a day, some Saturdays too. I would love to make enough to take a weekday off or so, but not so for now.

Comment: @Jack, I just tried to retire early - failed - have to go back to work and save save save. Two things I haven't seen recommended yet! 1. You need a little bingo in your overall portfolio some chance of extra cash - even if it's just a lottery ticket once a month, a shed you can rent, land (I'm Irish), a corner site, use your network is good advice 2. FWIW, Retirees are apparently not afraid of retirement, but are afraid of the loss of income. Work out how much you need in cash monthly to live and where it comes from. Thinking about that in advance is wise. Any problem repost pls

Comment: @SoftDotIE , My wife is playing the lotto angle. I am not crazy about it since she has been playing for the past few years. I believe it is definitely not a break even "investment". It was something she started when she was working so it wasn't so bad. Now I feel a little differently about it, even though I blew $20 last week on it myself. I do that every few months or so whether I need it or not....

Answer (score 30):

You *can* live comfortably on Social Security alone (my mother does it), but maybe not with a mortgage and a car payment, and maybe not in the area that you currently live. You might need to downsize both your car and your house into something that you can buy with cash or pay off very quickly.

Just moving your emergency fund to a higher-yield savings account does not solve the problem. Even if you have $10k saved up, a 3% account will only net you $300 per year, or $25 per month. I'd bet you can find ten times that in cost savings just by changing your lifestyle. Or use it to pay off the car and save that interest rate immediately.

I also don't think moving to Mexico is necessary. There are lots of places in the US that are very affordable (in my area you can buy a decent 2-bedroom home for $150k) without having to emigrate. Again, we're not talking about the lap of luxury, but if you truly want to "retire" that may be the best option.

If I were your financial advisor, I would not worry too much about tax-advantaged accounts yet. Taxes are not your problem. I would first look at your current budget: income, bills, etc. and see where you could cut to the bone. See how much you're spending on discretionary things like restaurants, vacations, etc. Sell the car and buy a beater. See how much equity you have in your home and whether it's feasible to downsize. Start saving like mad so that you *can* retire more comfortably on more than just social security.

Next I would look at your business and see where you can improve profitability. Are you not charging enough? Do you have expenses that could be reduced? Do you need to try and find more work, maybe even hire an employee to double the bottom line?

I do want to be encouraging - your situation is not bleak. You do have $500k in home equity and a *very* valuable skill that hopefully you can still utilize for enough time to live comfortable in retirement. It may just take difficult decisions or lifestyle changes, but that's something you and your wife will need to discuss to see what your retirement goals are, and what you can do to achieve them.

Comment: You hit on all the points I need to address. Yes I do need to bring in still more income, what I am charging now allows for vacation (in time, haven't had one in 7 years and working 11 hours a day to get this far). Also getting the wife on board with the spending will be the biggest task. I see tons of places to downsize, she does not. The place we have is meant to be an investment, as was the last home. Buy, fix up, sell for more equity. This place here that we have can be sold and get a new place with no mortgage if we play our cards right.

Comment: Is moving the emergency fund into a high yield savings a step in the right direction? Nope not looking to live extravagantly, just comfortable so if I want to do volunteer work I can afford to. My business operating costs are next to nothing, not enough work to keep an extra guy on, that's a story on its own... I am currently working as a sub for a business going through a massive expansion, been there for 5 years, recently realized I need to earn more than what they are paying by the hour, but will not give me an increase. I need 30% more than what I get now. Have gotten in the past maxed out

Comment: Well it doesn't _hurt_ to have higher savings rates but honestly it's not going to change anything by itself. If I handed you $300 today would that change your retirement outlook?

Comment: I understand that, but if I am going to have money sitting somewhere, it might as well be in someplace that gives more back. There are, I feel, or better yet, I hope, places where or things I can do with what I am earning to place funds. You have listed many other things I still need to do. I am try to follow Dave Ramsey's guidelines. My wife and I took his course years ago.

Comment: @Jack so did we :) so you can probably see some similarities. I agree, it's not a bad idea to use higher-yield savings accounts. I was just trying to illustrate that it's not going to "move the needle" it's not _wrong_, but it won't change your life. I think your intentions and attitude are great - it's just going to take some tough decisions.

Comment: @Jack I'm not in the USA so I don't know what the rules are on "high yield savings". As long as you can take the money out quickly if needed, then sure, you may as well keep some emergency money there and earn interest. If it's more like a CD then don't. But don't expect interest to work miracles - not in this economy - money has to be earned, not gotten for free, unless you're a billionaire investor. It's just a nice little bonus and not a real source of income.

Comment: @Jack since you are a carpenter... be aware that (because of the economy) a whole lot less houses are getting built from now on.

Comment: @user253751, the economy and the potential decline of home sales does have me concerned for stepping away from the place I have been working at as a subcontractor for the past 5 years. Building is still going crazy out here, but that is because all the building permits that were issued, creates a delay in the slow down. New homes may slow down, but remodeling is still out there.

Comment: @DStanley, I did see the similarities. I knew that the interest was not going to move mountains. I simply need it to do better than setting in a regular savings account. AND find the right place to do so.

Comment: I have to wonder if at this point selling the car would be a net positive.  If it was a new car, the loan was taken out against its price as a new car but now it's not worth anywhere close to that, so there's a good chance selling the car doesn't make up the price of both paying off the loan and buying a used car (which may cost more over time in maintenance anyway, especially if you have a warranty on the current car).

Answer (score 11):

One important item that seems to be missing from your analysis is your actual monthly cashflows. Maybe you are already performing monthly budgets, but based on the fact that your tax obligations have been a surprise year-over-year, I suspect that you may not be reviewing your monthly ins and outs at all.

How you will prepare for retirement is dependent on what your monthly expenses will be in the future. What your monthly expenses will be in the future, is largely a function of what your monthly expenses are today, adjusted by the actual lifestyle changes you are planning to make. If you aren't in the habit of doing a monthly budget based on what you are currently spending, it will likely be very difficult for you to anticipate what your future expenses will actually be.

After you have made a reasonable attempt at budgeting your future monthly expenses, you need to look at what sources of income you will have in retirement. How much in Social Security will you receive monthly? Do you or your wife have any private pension plans or other forms of guaranteed income? How much do you expect to make from whatever level of work you are planning to continue [such as low-volume woodworking] to supplement that income? And finally - how much extra retirement savings do you expect to earn between now and retirement?

With these numbers in front of you, you will need to be very honest with yourself about what lifestyle you will be able to afford. $500k in equity on a house is a massive potential asset - but only if you plan to use it productively. If you stay in that house forever, the equity will never put food on your table. To access it for actual cashflow, you basically have 3 options: (1) downsize immediately and invest the remaining funds for further growth; (2) use a 'reverse mortgage' style of financial arrangement which basically gives you cash now with a promise of giving up your house in the future [again - cash now would need to be invested]; or (3) take on a renter if your situation allows for it.  Simply planning to flip your house and buy a bigger one in the future will not provide cash for you in retirement.

Beyond the above, yes - once you have a handle on what your needs will be in the future, you will need to look at what will make sense for how to invest any funds between now and retirement. As pointed out elsewhere, this is not the biggest concern on the table.

Comment: Been watching the flow of money in and out of the house for years now. I am the only one working, making it tough. I see loads of places to trim expenses, but my wife does not. Not a good spot to be in. The plan is to sell this house and hopefully purchase the last home without a mortgage using the equity. The plan as it stands right now is to, Lord willin' work until 70 or longer, draw SS because I will be required to at that time. Hopefully with downsizing and cutting back on spending and working out of my shop be able to add to the SS. I still have good health so for now that is feasible.

Comment: @Jack Trying to maintain a budget without buy-in from your partner will be difficult and impossible. Perhaps it may help if you are more concrete about writing down explicitly what you expect to spend in all categories over the course of a month - and sit down together to compare results every month to see the discrepancy. Formal budgeting (together!) could really help. There are many methods; one of the simplest you can find by googling "You Need A Budget", or by searching the 'budget' tag on this site. Good luck!

Comment: I know that is what needs to be done, I wish it was simple as that. It may sound simple and it may be simple for some, but it is not for us, (or me?). We have issues we need to work through.

Comment: But it must be done so somehow, Lord willing we can do this...

Comment: @Jack Yes sorry for maybe sounding trite, I know the steps are brief but they are not easy.